# What is "New Virtual Output" in kde screen share (portal) dialog?

Tags: kde, wayland, xdg, recording, obs-studio

In kde wayland when you choose the pipewire source in obs, you get the Desktop Portal dialog that allows you to choose one of your screens or a "Full Workspace". But also there is an option "New Virtual Output".

[image]

When I choose it, in system settings in Monitors I see another screen appeared with no name.

[image]

What is a purpose of it? How it is intended to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Where you able to figure this out ?

In my opinion, the purpose is to have a separate emulated screen that you show to your video conference and where you only put what you want to be visible. This is usually done with a two monitors setup where on one you only put what you want to display, but maybe you only have one monitor or maybe you need one more, whatever, it's a separate screen and you will be only streaming this one.

How to use it, I don't know. I've only been able to send windows to it using keyboard shortcuts but then I can't interact with them because "my mouse isn't really on the window". I'm looking at how you could display it on your real monitor when needed but haven't found any information yet. If you've figured it out I would be really interested.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/421722)

Comment: I don't feel like I'm not answering the question but rather only half of it. I think I fairly explained "What is a purpose of it?"

Comment: You’ve provided a reasonable guess, but it seems to me that even the purpose part of the question can’t really be answered without explaining how to use it — if you can’t use it, how can you determine whether the purpose you imagine for it is actually its purpose?

Comment: got it. agreed.

Comment: > I'm looking at how you could display it on your real monitor
You can just drag that virtual screen above real one, so it will be mirrored. But again, I do not understand the purpose of it. Because you can just share a real one screen.